# Pulse generation options for 1.695 MHz

Tags: pulse

I have a design in which a [CPLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_programmable_logic_device) (complex programmable logic device) is used to generate two pulse signals at 1.695 MHz. Of course the CPLD does some other tasks but I only need the pulse generation and for that a CPLD is to oversized. Now i am looking for other options to generate two different pulses with following requirements:

- 1.695 MHz frequency
- two Pulse signals
- variable duty cycle

My first idea is a microcontroller with a 100 Mhz oscillator, but if anyone knows an already existing IC for this task, I would prefer the IC.

Comment: What's a CPLD? Put a little explanation and maybe a link in your question. You should also fix your capitalisation and punctuation to improve credibility.

Comment: Whats a CPLD? Really? But anyway, it doesn't matter because the CPLD is not part of the question. -->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_programmable_logic_device   BTW: Im not native speaker, so feel free to edit my post and i will accept it

Comment: how small do you want it? in terms of area, pin count, or power and cost?

Comment: cost and power doesn't matter. Complexity and number of components or area on the pcb is more important

Comment: I haven't seen the term CPLD in 40 years of reading electronics articles or on this site where just about everything is discussed. I'm sure many others won't know either. I fixed your post.

Comment: @Transistor I would consider it only a bit less common than FPGA, actually...

Comment: It's about 11:1 for FPGA on the EE.SE tag count. 136 posts tagged for CPLD.

Comment: @Transistor I don't know. Is CPLD already obsolete or just never popular? It was still taught as part of undergrad's digital logic class not very long ago. For those who don't know CPLDs, what would they consider to implement small digital logic? There aren't many convenient options, are there?

Comment: yes, SPLDs and CPLDs were at the beginning of programable logic devices years ago. but they are still used today by many companies for simple logic, because they are a cheap option for programmable logic

Comment: I'd throw a ATtiny25/45/85 at this, with an appropriate crystal to get (a multiple of) that frequency.

Comment: As an aside, is this for some RFID application?

Comment: @S.G - Historically, there is no such thing as an SPLD. First there were PLDs, and when they started getting more complex the term CPLD was invented.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams thanks, an ATiny is also my favorite idea for that. Do you have any experience on clocks/pulses in terms of jitter etc?  Btw  it is for an inductive powering application

Comment: Not really. That application is outside my domain. But hum a few bars and I'll see if I can pick it up.

Comment: I have done some research and I think I have two possible solutions: 1. take a 100Mhz quarz, a µC and generate my pulses at 1.695 MHZ. OR: 2. I take a resistor set oscillator like this one --> http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1799 generate a clock that is a multiple of 1.695MHz and use it with a µC to generate the pulses. Which one would you prefer?